# Background not across whole page

Tags: html, css

A really stupid question (I think), but why is my background not across the whole page? I only get a little bar at the top of the page.

**My code:**

Html

```
<body>
<div class="homepage">
<div class="headtext">
<h3>Text1</h3>
<h5>Text2</h5>
</div>
<div class="input">
<input> </input>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Css

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
background: transparent;
}

.homepage {
background: #FF4632;
}

.headtext {
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
top: 25%;
}

.headtext h3 {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}

.headtext h5 {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}
```

Thanks for helping me

Comment: When rendered in the browser, your HTML code (and everyone's) isn't taking the full page.
If you put a specific background color to your page, you'll only see this background color put in the background of your `.homepage` element and all child elements.
You need a way to apply the background color to the full page, for example on the `<html>` tag, so instead of applying the background on `.homepage`, you'll end up applying it on `html`. See [here](http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_background_codes.cfm)

Comment: add height:100vh; to the class .homepage to make it expand to all screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:`position:fixed;` the `.homepage`**

Give `position:fixed; height:100%;width:100%;` to the `.homepage` to apply the background color to the whole body

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
background: transparent;
}

.homepage {
background: #FF4632;
  position:fixed;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

.headtext {
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
top: 25%;
}

.headtext h3 {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}

.headtext h5 {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="homepage">
<div class="headtext">
<h3>Text1</h3>
<h5>Text2</h5>
</div>
<div class="input">
<input/>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

**Solution 2: apply background-color to the whole body**

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
font-size: 100%;
vertical-align: baseline;
background: transparent;
}

body{
background: #FF4632;
}

.headtext {
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, 0);
top: 25%;
}

.headtext h3 {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}

.headtext h5 {
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Questrial', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="homepage">
<div class="headtext">
<h3>Text1</h3>
<h5>Text2</h5>
</div>
<div class="input">
<input/>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
background: #FF4632;
}
```

replace `.homepage` with `body`

Answer (score 1):

The root cause is because when you are styling the header tags, it is no longer inside the "homepage" `div`.

See this JS Fiddle -

https://jsfiddle.net/tqok771m/

```
.headtext {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    top: 25%;
}
```

This is due to your use of `position: fixed;`

One easy solution is to set a height on your homepage DIV with something like height:1000px;

Answer (score 0):

Put the background color on your body element, not the div.

```
body {
    background: #FF4632;
}
```